# POST an item to JSON server db- Angular

Tags: node.js, angular, express, mean-stack, json-server

I'm trying to POST an Item to my db in my json server. I'm sending the POST request from Angular. When I do so, I get the following error:

**Note: when I do the get in a the GET end point it works fine. I'm very new on the server side**

> POST ERROR 404:
>   Http failure response for http://localhost:3000/addMember: 404 Not Found

**SERVER.JS**

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const request = require('request');
const app = express();
....

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.static('assets'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.disable('x-powered-by');
app.use(xssFilter());
app.use(nosniff());
app.set('etag', false);
app.use(
  helmet({
    noCache: true
  })
);
app.use(
  hsts({
    maxAge: 15552000 // 180 days in seconds
  })
);

app.use(
  express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist/softrams-racing'), {
    etag: false
  })
);

app.get('/api/members', (req, res) => {
  request('http://localhost:3000/members', (err, response, body) => {
    if (response.statusCode <= 500) {
      res.send(body);
    }
  });
});

// TODO: Dropdown!
app.get('/api/teams', (req, res) => {
  request('http://localhost:3000/teams', (err, response, body) => {
    if (response.statusCode <= 500) {
      res.send(body);
    }
  });
});

    // Submit Form!
    app.post('/api/members', function(request, response) {
  request.post('http://localhost:3000/members', (err, response, body) => {
    if (response.statusCode <= 500) {
      req.send(body);
    }
  });
});



  app.get('*', (req, res) => {
      res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'dist/softrams-racing/index.html'));
    });

    app.listen('8000', () => {
      console.log('Vrrrum Vrrrum! Server starting!');
    });
```

**ANGULAR**

```
addMember(memberForm: Member) {
    this.http.post(`${this.api}/addMember`, memberForm).subscribe(
      data => {
        console.log('POST Request is successful ', data);
      },
      error => {
        console.log('Error', error);
      }
    );
  }
```

UPDATE:
in my console i see this `POST /addMember 404 12.105 ms - 2` and If i go to `http://localhost:3000/addMember` directly in the browser I see an empty object `{}` and if I go here `http://localhost:3000/` I see this message **To access and modify resources, you can use any HTTP method GET POST PUT PATCH DELETE OPTIONS**

Comment: Could you show your code of GET api. It seems like you try to call remote API inside your API.

I think root cause is you using param `req` to call other API.

Can you try using : `request = require('request')` instead of `req`

Comment: @Scofield I have updated the question with the GET code

Comment: It seems like whatever you have running on localhost:3000 simply doesn't have a handler for POST requests to the URL you've given it…

Comment: @Scofield im using request already i have it define at the top of my file

Comment: @WillAlexander in my console i see this ``POST /addMember 404 12.105 ms - 2`` If i go to ``http://localhost:3000/addMember`` directly in the browser I see an empty object ``{}``.  and if I go here ``http://localhost:3000/`` I see this message ``To access and modify resources, you can use any HTTP method 
GET POST PUT PATCH DELETE OPTIONS``

Comment: If you're getting a 404, it's almost certainly because whatever is running there doesn't handle a POST to /addMember. What exactly is running on port 3000?

Comment: @WillAlexander on server 3000 is JSON server

Comment: Can we see your db.json file please?

Comment: I suspect you need to make your POST request to `/members`, not to `/addMember`

Comment: @WillAlexander OMG! you are a genius!

Comment: @WillAlexander feel free to put it as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that you are making your POST request to a route which your JSON server does not handle.  Change the URL to `http://localhost:3000/members`, and it should work fine!

(The routes on a json-server correspond to the elements in your `db.json` file.)

Answer (score 1):

Try to change your code like this:

```
addMember(memberForm: Member) {
    this.http.post(`${this.api}/api/addMember`, memberForm).subscribe(
      data => {
        console.log('POST Request is successful ', data);
      },
      error => {
        console.log('Error', error);
      }
    );
  }
```

From the error it is shown that your service is expecting the request at `http://localhost:3000/api/addMember` but your console.log shows that you are sending post request at `http://locatlhost:3000/addMember`